# When does map/reduce in MongoDB actually trigger the replace?

Tags: mongodb

According to the docs at http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce, when using the REPLACE  out directive,

> the output will be inserted into a collection which will atomically replace any existing collection with the same name.

Does this mean that the data is collected into a temporary collection while the M/R process is running and then finally does some sort of rename to replace the previous output?

If this is the case, I could run regular batch processes to update a collection without running the risk that it would be empty (or only partially full) at any point in time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is correct. The way replace works right now for non-sharded output is that it will acquire a write lock, drop the old database, and rename the temp collection into the output collection and release the write lock. Since there is only one write lock, you are essentially guaranteed that this operation is atomic. However, the same cannot be said for merge and reduce.